# AtomicResult Error In My Flutter App after Windows Update

Tags: flutter, kotlin, dart

Just updated Windows and my app won't compile. A file called AtomicRestult seems to be the problem, I have never heard of this file.

The error message that appears is below:

```
e: C:\UsersAppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (87, 2): Missing '}
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (29, 9): Class 'AtomicResult' is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun success(p0: Any?): Unit defined in io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel.Result
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (46, 5): 'success' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (47, 9): Unresolved reference: scope
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (50, 37): Unresolved reference: operation
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (55, 13): Unresolved reference: result
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (59, 5): 'error' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (60, 9): Unresolved reference: scope
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (63, 37): Unresolved reference: operation
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (71, 13): Unresolved reference: result
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (75, 5): 'notImplemented' overrides nothing
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (76, 9): Unresolved reference: scope
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (79, 37): Unresolved reference: operation
e: C:\Users\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\amplify_core-0.2.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\amazonaws\amplify\amplify_core\AtomicResult.kt: (84, 13): Unresolved reference: result

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':amplify_core:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

The AtomicResult file is below:

```
package com.amazonaws.amplify.amplify_core

import io.flutter.Log
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean

/**
 * Thread-safe [MethodChannel.Result] wrapper which prevents multiple replies and automatically posts
 * results to the main thread.
 */
class AtomicResult(private val result: MethodChannel.Result, private val operation: String?) :
    MethodChannel.Result {
    private companion object {
        class AtomicResult(private val result: MethodChannel.Result, private val operation: String?) :
                MethodChannel.Result {
            private companion object {
                /**
                 * Scope for performing result handling.
                 * Method channel results must be sent on the main (UI) thread.
                 */
                val scope = MainScope()
            }
        val scope = MainScope()
    }

    /**
     * Whether a response has been sent.
     */
    private val isSent = AtomicBoolean(false)

    override fun success(value: Any?) {
        scope.launch {
            if (isSent.getAndSet(true)) {
                Log.w(
                    "AtomicResult(${operation})",
                    "Attempted to send success value after initial reply"
                )
                return@launch
            }
            result.success(value)
        }
    }

    override fun error(errorCode: String?, errorMessage: String?, errorDetails: Any?) {
        scope.launch {
            if (isSent.getAndSet(true)) {
                Log.w(
                    "AtomicResult(${operation})",
                    """
                    Attempted to send error value after initial reply:
                    | PlatformException{code=${errorCode}, message=${errorMessage}, details=${errorDetails}}
                    """.trimMargin()
                )
                return@launch
            }
            result.error(errorCode, errorMessage, errorDetails)
        }
    }

    override fun notImplemented() {
        scope.launch {
            if (isSent.getAndSet(true)) {
                Log.w(
                    "AtomicResult(${operation})",
                    "Attempted to send notImplemented value after initial reply"
                )
                return@launch
            }
            result.notImplemented()
        }
    }
}
```

I have no idea what this file does and not sure what could possibly be wrong. I suspect that it could be the code but can't be too sure.

The below is a response to a suggestion.
I updated amplify core and I get the error message below:

```
Because no versions of amplify_auth_cognito match >0.2.10 <0.3.0 and amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.0 <0.2.1 depends on amplify_core 0.2.0, amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.0 <0.2.1-∞ or >0.2.10 <0.3.0 requires amplify_core 0.2.0.
And because amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.1 <0.2.2 depends on amplify_core 0.2.1 and amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.2 <0.2.3 depends on amplify_core 0.2.2, amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.0 <0.2.3-∞ or >0.2.10 <0.3.0 requires amplify_core 0.2.0 or 0.2.1 or 0.2.2.
And because amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.3 <0.2.4 depends on amplify_core 0.2.3 and amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.4 <0.2.5 depends on amplify_core 0.2.4, amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.0 <0.2.5-∞ or >0.2.10 <0.3.0 requires amplify_core 0.2.0 or 0.2.1 or 0.2.2 or 0.2.3 or 0.2.4.
And because amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.5 <0.2.6 depends on amplify_core 0.2.5 and amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.6 <0.2.7 depends on amplify_core 0.2.6, amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.0 <0.2.7-∞ or >0.2.10 <0.3.0 requires amplify_core 0.2.0 or 0.2.1 or 0.2.2 or 0.2.3 or 0.2.4 or 0.2.5 or 0.2.6.
And because amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.7 <0.2.8 depends on amplify_core 0.2.7 and amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.8 <0.2.9 depends on amplify_core 0.2.8, amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.0 <0.2.9-∞ or >0.2.10 <0.3.0 requires amplify_core 0.2.0 or 0.2.1 or 0.2.2 or 0.2.3 or 0.2.4 or 0.2.5 or 0.2.6 or 0.2.7 or 0.2.8.
And because amplify_auth_cognito >=0.2.9 <0.2.10 depends on amplify_core 0.2.9 and amplify_auth_cognito 0.2.10 depends on amplify_core 0.2.10, amplify_auth_cognito ^0.2.0 requires amplify_core 0.2.0 or 0.2.1 or 0.2.2 or 0.2.3 or 0.2.4 or 0.2.5 or 0.2.6 or 0.2.7 or 0.2.8 or 0.2.9 or 0.2.10.
So, because newday depends on both amplify_auth_cognito ^0.2.0 and amplify_core ^0.6.6, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because newday depends on both amplify_auth_cognito ^0.2.0 and amplify_core ^0.6.6, version solving failed.)
```

Below are my dependencies

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  rxdart: ^0.27.5

  provider: ^6.0.3
  amplify_flutter: <1.0.0  #1.0.0
  amplify_auth_cognito: ^0.2.0 #0.2.0
  hooks_riverpod: ^1.0.3
  flutter_hooks: ^0.18.2
  riverpod: ^1.0.3
  curved_navigation_bar: ^1.0.3
  just_audio:
  amplify_core: ^0.6.6
  video_player: ^2.3.0
  page_transition: ^2.0.5
  flash_card: ^0.0.7
  community_material_icon: ^5.9.55
  flutter_swipable: ^1.2.1
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is being generated from a package you are using. The version of the package is quite old and you need to update it.
Update `amplify_core` package in pubspec.yaml file

`amplify_core: ^0.6.6`

Comment: I tried that, however I did it again, the error message is in my question at the bottom. Could it perhaps be that I have to rewrite my sign in/sign up page? @UsamaKarim

Comment: It's fixed, you were right. Had to update some code too. @UsamaKarim